# How can I solve Steam Error -107/Secure Connection Failed?

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I need help with fixing Steam on my PC.

Whenever I try to use Steam via their website or the Steam platform or anything it does not load at all.

- From my *browser* I either just get a blank page or "Secure Connection Failed"
- On the *platform* I either also get a blank page or *"Error -107"*

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Steam; Didn't work.
- Running a complete PC scan; nothing there.
- I contacted Steam's support from my other computer; no response for 4 weeks now.
- Rebuilding my ClientRegistry.blob; didnt work.
- Validating Game Cache; didnt work.
- I asked on the steam support Reddit page; no answer.
- I tried working out some other things and nothing helps.

I don't have a proxy, I have a stable internet connection with a modem and I'm not in Steam's Offline mode.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or anything ? How do you connect to the internet ?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you in Offline Mode?

Comment: I dont have proxies,I have a stable internet connection with a modem and I'm not in offline mode

Comment: RE: The other PC you're using to contact Steam support - are you doing this on the same internet connection?

Comment: I was doing it from the same internet connection but with a different IP and I also tried with my own IP on my other PC and steam still works